# Node.js: SCP file and perserve permissions

Tags: node.js, ssh, file-permissions

I'm using the `node-ssh2` module to copy files to remote servers. In general I don't have the ability to change the default umask on the servers. But I need the remote file's mode to be 0666 after it's copied.

If I set it first locally and then just run `scp -p <localfile> <remote>` it works fine, preserving the 0666 permission. How do I do this with node.js? I've tried using `node-ssh2` and starting an sftp session. Then I do `sftp.fastPut` but the permissions are always set to 0644 on the server.

As I said I'm currently using the `node-ssh2` module and I'd like to stick with that but if I need use something different that is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Specify it in the options argument for fastPut:

```
sftp.fastPut( 'local_path', 'remote_path', { mode: 0666 }, callback );
```

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't work. It seems that the mode is not an option for fastPut. https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2-streams/blob/master/SFTPStream.md

Comment: @SeanLynch Oh, my bad. Sorry, I'll delete this answer in a minute if I can't find a proper solution to edit it.

Comment: No worries. I thought that would work too. I have also tried `sftp.createWriteStream(<remote>, {mode: 0666})`. The `createWriteStream` function *does* take the mode option, but it get's overridden by the server and ends up as 0644.

Comment: Here 'remote_path' means 'remote_path/file_name'. Error is thrown  without file name.